# How is "I saw him going toward that room." understood?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Imagine that the police is looking for witnesses to a killing, and they ask me if I saw a person. After I say I saw him, I am asked where I saw him and, being close the place where I saw him, I say "I saw him going toward that room."

How would the sentence be normally understood?

- I saw him while I was going toward that room.
- I saw him, and he was going toward that room.

Comment: It's ambiguous and requires a context, but I'd say that normally I'd understand it to mean "When I saw him, **he** was headed in the direction of that room", not "When I saw him, **I** was headed in the direction of that room"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it would be understood as the second statement.
When speaking to the police, a lawyer, or in a court of law, I would be very precise and to 
make it clear that he was the one going toward the room, it is safer that say anyone of these:

> When I saw him, he was going toward that room.

> He was going toward that room when I saw him.

> I saw him as he was going toward that room.

If you were the one going toward the room use you first statement. You could also use "As I was going toward that room, I saw him."